# Call the stored procedure of through private endpoint using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure

I have created a private endpoint  for SQL Server in Azure portal. How to call stored procedure from C#.NET through private endpoint?

I have a few questions:

- Will the connection string is vary when I migrate from public to private?
- Is there any private endpoint URL to access the db from C#.NET?
- Is the private endpoint will support older version of .NET framework 4.5?

Comment: Could you share what have you tried? Share the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: should be the same if you are using azure sql

Comment: Private endpoint doesn't mean _anything_ to C#. It's just network. You just need to ensure that the host running the app (it could be an app written in anything) can connect to the private endpoint.